# Why is my Navbar not displaying inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't figure out what I've done to my code, but unfortunately the Navbar no longer displays inline as a Bootstrap Navbar, any help would be appreciated.

```css
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-width: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(150, 155, 155, );
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}


.list {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
```

```html
  
  <div class="list" style="Position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px;">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav">
          <h3><li><a href="/">Home</a></li></h6>
          <h3><li><a href="group.html">Team</a></li></h3>
          <h3><li><a href="services.html">Krygyzstan</a></li></h3>
          <h3><li><a href="positions.html">Blog</a></li></h3>
          <h3><li><a href="positions.html">Expeditions</a></li></h3>
              </ul>
              </div>
        </nav>
       <style>
      text-align:justify;
       </style>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `h3`s inside the `a` tags and remove all unnecessary classes especially `navbar-justified` in the `ul` . The h3s interfere with the li and ul.
Here is the code that worked for me in a code pen

```
 <div class="list" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px;">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="group.html"><h3>Team</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html"><h3>Krygyzstan</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="positions.html"><h3>Blog</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="positions.html"><h3>Expeditions</h3></a></li>
          </ul>
          </div>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3's navbars are supposed to be set up so that they are responsive and collapsable.  You need to add the navbar header and the collapse menu.  Im assuming that you are using bootstrap 3 here so it should look something like the following:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/"><h3>Home</h3></a></li>
            <li><a href="group.html"><h3>Team</h3></a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html"><h3>Krygyzstan</h3></a></li>
            <li><a href="positions.html"><h3>Blog</h3></a></li>
            <li><a href="positions.html"><h3>Expeditions</h3></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Not sure why you have the h3 tags in your navigation but if you really need them there technically web standards say that you should not have block elements inside of inline elements so your h3 tags should technically be inside of the a tag but then you will have to restyle a bunch of stuff because bootstraps styles won't work with them outside the a tag so it is up to you whether you want to do that or not.  But if you do your structure should look like the following:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><h3><a href="/">Home</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="group.html">Team</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="services.html">Krygyzstan</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="positions.html">Blog</a></h3></li>
            <li><h3><a href="positions.html">Expeditions</a></h3></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And then you would have to restyle the h3 tags and a tags inside of bootstraps navbar for it to look the same as the normal bootstrap navbar.

If you dont want the collapseable nav then I suggest just writing your own nav and css something like the following:

```
<nav>
     <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="group.html">Team</a></li>
                     <li><a href="services.html">Krygyzstan</li>
                     <li>a href="positions.html">Blog</a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</nav>
```

Then add your own styles like

```
nav {
  background:#000;
  display:block;
  height:100%;
}
nav ul{
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
nav ul li {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
nav ul li a{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 15px;
  margin:0 10px;
  background:#777;
  color:#fff;
}
```

But the first example that I put down should get your navbar working for you just remember that with bootstrap 3 they are supposed to be collapsable so you need to keep with the structure that they provide.